# StateFlowImpl collect has a while loop,If I use it on UI Thread,Why it doesn't block UI Thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

If I use while loop on launch,it will keep running,the click event will not execute,eventually lead to ANR.
StateFlowImpl collect has a while loop,When will it exit the loop,this is my case:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(0)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        launch {
            while (true) {
                Log.d(TAG, "while")
            }
        }
        launch {
            flow.collect {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

// This is StateFlowImpl 
override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
    val slot = allocateSlot()
    try {
        if (collector is SubscribedFlowCollector) collector.onSubscription()
        val collectorJob = currentCoroutineContext()[Job]
        var oldState: Any? = null // previously emitted T!! | NULL (null -- nothing emitted yet)
        while (true) {
            val newState = _state.value
            collectorJob?.ensureActive()
            if (oldState == null || oldState != newState) {
                collector.emit(NULL.unbox(newState))
                oldState = newState
            }
            if (!slot.takePending()) {
                slot.awaitPending()
            }
        }
    } finally {
        freeSlot(slot)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Blocking" and "never returning" are 2 different things.

The term "blocking" usually refers to using the thread exclusively, preventing it from doing other things (at least on the JVM).

Coroutines allow to have such a `while(true)` without blocking a thread. **As long as there are *suspension points* in the loop**, it gives an opportunity for the thread to go execute some other code from another coroutine and later come back.

- In the case of `StateFlowImpl`, the `collector.emit()` call is a suspension point because `emit()` is a suspending function, so at that point the thread can go execute other coroutines.
- If you don't have a suspension point (as in your first `launch`), the loop is indeed blocking the thread because it never yields it to other coroutines. This is what prevents other code from running on UI thread. You can artifically add suspension points in your loop by calling [yield](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/yield.html):

```kotlin
launch {
    while (true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "while")
        yield() // allow the thread to go execute other coroutines and come back
    }
}
```

You can also run blocking code on other threads than the main thread. This might be more appropriate if you're doing blocking IO or CPU-intensive stuff.

Note that using `yield` also makes this coroutine cancellable for free. Otherwise you would have to replace `while(true)` by `while(currentCoroutineContext().isActive)` to ensure you stop looping when the coroutine is cancelled.

> When will it exit the loop

Now a `while(true)` loop indeed never returns. When you write the caller code, calling `collect` on `StateFlow` prevents any following code in the same coroutine from being executed. This is because code is executed *sequentially* within a coroutine even when suspend functions are involved (it makes it easy to reason about).

If you want to execute this `collect` *concurrently* with other code, you have to call it in a separate coroutine (using `launch`, `async`, or other coroutine builders) - and this is what you do here.

```kotlin
launch {
    flow.collect {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $it")
    }
    someOtherCode() // unreachable code
}
someOtherCode2() // this is OK
```

However, **the coroutine calling `StateFlow.collect` never ends by itself**, it needs to be cancelled from outside. This is usually controlled via the coroutine scope used to launch the coroutine.

In your case, you're making the activity implement `CoroutineScope by MainScope()`. This is not advisable, because you don't cancel that scope anywhere. Android [already provides a ready-to-use coroutine scope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) in components such as Activities which have a lifecycle (see `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` library). It's called `lifecycleScope`. You should launch your coroutines in this scope so they automatically get cancelled when the activity is destroyed:

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope


lifecycleScope.launch { // cancelled when the Activity is destroyed
    while (true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "while")
        yield()
    }
}
lifecycleScope.launch { // cancelled when the Activity is destroyed
    flow.collect {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $it")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply，I can understand "Blocking" and "never returning",What puzzles me is no other operations can be performed, such as some click events, because such a while(true) on UI thread,In this case,When will it be possible to exit this loop?

Comment: @summer the `while(true)` in your first coroutine doesn't contain any suspension point (only blocking calls like `Log.d`), so it is effectively blocking the UI thread. The difference with the one from the `StateFlowImpl` is that in the state flow's `collect` there is a suspending `emit()` call, which yields the thread to other coroutines. This loop will never end though, unless you cancel the coroutine running `collect` (for instance when your activity is destroyed).

Comment: @summer I updated my answer to explain a bit better based on your edited question. I hope this clarifies that